# $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$, interior, product topology

Tags: general-topology

For arbitrary products, is there a relation between $A=\Pi_i \text{int}(X_i)$ and $B=\text{int}(\Pi_iX_i)$? $B$ cannot generally be a subset of $A$, so it should be $A\subset B$. But since $A$ is not generally open, I'm not seeing how this can be shown.

Comment: The short answer is that $A=B$ if the set $J=\{i\in I\,:\, X_i\ne Y_i\}$ is finite, whereas $B=\emptyset$ if $J$ is infinite.

Comment: @Gae.S. $Y_i$ is the ambient space or vice versa?

Comment: $Y_i$ is the ambient space to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the X's be (0,1) and space a countable product of R's.
$A = \Pi_i int(X_i) = \Pi_i (0,1)$ is not empty.
$B = int \Pi_i (X_i) = int\Pi_i (0,1).$ is empty
because the open base sets have the form
$X_1 ×..× X_n × R × R ×...$ for some finite integer n.
Thus A is not a subset of B.

Comment: Ah, I think I had things a little backwards in my question. I believe this is what I was thinking of when I said $B$ cannot generally be in $A$ (it should have been the other way around, as you noted). Is the relation $B\subset A$ generally true?

Comment: Indeed, B cannot be in A because the only things in B are points and B is not a point. @user124910

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{gae}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}\gae{int}$
Assuming the $X_i$ to be subsets of topological spaces $Y_i$, and that $\int\prod_i X_i$ refers to the interior in $\prod_i Y_i$, recall that by the definition of product topology:

> A set $\Omega\subseteq\prod\limits_{i\in I} Y_i$ is open if and only if there is a subset $\mathcal S$ of the set $$\mathcal R:=\left\{\prod_{i\in I} U_i\,:\, U_i\text{ open in }Y_i\land \left\lvert\{i\in I\,:\, Y_i\ne U_i\}\right\rvert\text{ is finite}\right\}$$ such that $\bigcup\mathcal S=\Omega$.

Call $\pi_j:\prod_{i\in I}Y_i\to Y_j$ the projection map $\pi_j(x)=x_j$ and, more generally, given $J\subseteq I$ such that $J\ne \emptyset$, $$\pi_J:\prod_{i\in I}Y_i\to \prod_{j\in J} Y_j\\\pi_J(x)=\left.x\right \rvert_J$$

It is clear from the definition of product topology that all the subsets $H\subseteq \prod_{i\in I} Y_i$ such that the set $\{i\in I\,:\, \pi_i[H]\ne Y_i\}$ is infinite must have empty interior. Therefore, in most cases of $\lvert I\rvert\ge\aleph_0$ your $B$ will be empty, whereas $A$ won't.

It is elementary to prove that all the maps $\pi_j$ are continuous and open (and, more generally, so are the maps $\pi_J$ for $J\ne \emptyset$).

The discussion about $A=\prod_{i\in I}\int X_i$, $C=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and $B=\int C$ may be summarised as such:

- if $\{i\in I\,:\, X_i\ne Y_i\}$ is an infinite set, then $B=\emptyset$, and therefore $B\subseteq A\subseteq C$. Under AC, $A=B$ if and only if some $X_i$ has empty interior.
- if $\{i\in I\,:\, X_i\ne Y_i\}$ is a finite set, then $B=A\subseteq C$. In fact, $A$ is an open subset of $C$ and therefore $A\subseteq B$. Moreover, let $D$ be open and $A\subsetneq D\subseteq C$. Let $x\in D\setminus A$. The defining property of $x\notin A$ is that for all $a\in A$ there must be some $i\in I$ such that $x_i\ne a_i$. Since $A$ is a product of sets, I claim the stronger fact that there is some $i\in I$ such that, for all $a\in A$, $x_i\ne a_i$. In fact, if for all $i$ there were some $a\in \prod_i \int X_i$ such that $x_i=a_i$, then by definition of product $x_i\in \int X_i$ for all $i$, and therefore $x\in \prod_i \int X_i$. Absurd. Now, let $s\in I$ such that $x_s\ne a_s$ for all $a\in A$. This means that $\pi_s[D]\ne \pi_s[A]$ and, specifically, that $$\int X_s=\pi_s[A]\subsetneq \pi_s[D]\subseteq \pi_s[C]= X_s$$
  But $D$ is open and $\pi_s$ is open, against the definition of interior. Therefore indeed $A=\int C=B$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a point $\{x_i\}\in\prod_i\text{int}(X_i)$, then, $x_i\in \text{int}(X_i),\forall i$. Fix $i_0$ and consider $x_{i_0}\in U_{i_0}\subseteq_{\text{open}}X_{i_0}$, then $\{x_i\}\in\pi_{i_0}^{-1}(U_{i_0})\subseteq_{\text{open}}\prod_iX_i\implies\{x_i\}\in\text{int}\big(\prod_iX_i\big).$ Here $\pi_{i_0}$ is the the projection on the $i_0$-th coordinate. So, $\prod_i\text{int}(X_i)\subseteq \text{int}\big(\prod_iX_i\big).$

Next choose $\{x_i\}\in\text{int}\big(\prod_iX_i\big)$. Then we have a basic open set $V$ in $\prod_iX_i$ containing $\{x_i\}$. So we have $i_1,....,i_n$ such that, $V=\bigcap_{k=1}^n\pi_{i_k}^{-1}(U_{i_k})$ with $U_{i_k}\subseteq_{\text{open}}X_{i_k},\forall k$. Therefore for each $k$ we have, $x_{i_k}\in U_{i_k}\implies x_{i_k}\in \text{int}(X_{i_k})$. And for any $i\not\in \{i_1,...,i_n\}$ we can **not** say, $x_i\in \text{int}(X_i)$ .

Comment: I'm trying to see where your argument in the first paragraph conflicts with William's example

Comment: Unless $X_i$ is equal to the whole topological space $Y_i$ for all but finitely many values of $i$, $\operatorname{int}\prod_i X_i=\emptyset$ in $\prod_i Y_i$. In that case, the inequality $\prod_i\operatorname{int}X_i\subseteq \operatorname{int}\prod_i X_i$ is verified in very rare circumstances.